# How to generate XML from XSD using perl

Tags: xml, perl

i am trying to genarate XML from xsd using perl 
can anyone guide me in right direction 
thank you

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace="urn:books"
        xmlns:bks="urn:books">
 <xsd:element name="books" type="bks:BooksForm"/>
<xsd:complexType name="BooksForm">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="book" 
              type="bks:BookForm" 
              minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexType>
 <xsd:complexType name="BookForm">
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="author"   type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="title"    type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="genre"    type="xsd:string"/>
  <xsd:element name="price"    type="xsd:float" />
  <xsd:element name="pub_date" type="xsd:date" />
  <xsd:element name="review"   type="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:sequence>
<xsd:attribute name="id"   type="xsd:string"/>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: In what way are you "trying to generate XML from xsd"? Are you trying to generate sample XML or are you trying to create real data that validates against that XML?

Comment: i am trying generate sample XML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of anything that specifically generates example XML from and XSD file in Perl. However if I were approaching the task I would start by looking at [XML::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile) and [XML::Pastor](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Pastor) which both support some form of XSD -> Perl marshaling. There may be some way to boostrap their XSD parsing and build a random document generator from that.

Another, much less favorable, option is to use my own [XML::Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Toolkit) to generate objects from the XSD file and use those to build a generator for your document. This wouldn't be trivial or even necessarily "sane", but I think it should be possible.

There simply aren't many tools for XSD in Perl at the moment.